# Latitude/Longitude Math Question (Distance Between Two Coordinates)

Tags: c#, database, math, optimization

I currently have a database query that calculate the distance between every store in the database from there to a "home" location. I'm calculating the flight distance using this formula.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Then I'm ordering them and displaying them. I discovered a much better way to do it is only search for stores whose latitude/longitude are within a range.

For example instead of calculating distance between each store in the database (over 30000), only group ones with lat/longs within a certain range and calculate distance between those.

Right now I'm trying to found out how to calculate the actual bounds. The distance has to be below 5km. So I divide 5 by 100 and cap the latitude and longitude by those amounts.

```
SELECT storeid, storedescription, address, city, storebannerdescription, lat, lon,
        ROUND (gc_dist (lat, lon, 43.758152, -79.746639), 1) AS distance
        FROM storelatlon
        WHERE ((lat-43.758152) < 0.05 AND (lat -43.758152) > -0.05) AND ( (lon-(-79.746639)) < 0.05 AND (lon-(-79.746639)) > -0.05)
        ORDER BY Distance
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but I will note that subtracting angular measures doesn't tell you anything about distances.

Comment: What's the question? I assume it's "Is this a valid or good implementation?" Also, what database are you using? Some databases have support for lat/long calculations (such as Oracle Locator), but that is not _necessarily_ free (Oracle Spatial is not and it can be hard to tell where the lines end with Locator and start with Spatial). Other databases also provide basic support, including MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method could work, but depending on how widely distributed your stores are, you may need to refine your bounds a bit because as you go up in latitute, you cross more longitude over a given distance.  You may get too many or too few points just filtering by 0.05 deg for all latitudes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using PostgreSQL based on your use of gc_dist. As long as you have PostGIS installed, then you can perform the desired logic using built-in functionality.

You will have to prepare your table for this:

First, store your location as a PostGIS point. I suggest using WGS-84 for geographic calculations.

After you do that, then you can query for all points within any given distance from your desired location using [`ST_Contains`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Contains.html) and [`ST_Buffer`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Buffer.html), where `ST_Buffer` wraps the center point that you want to find neighbors for (-79.746639, 43.758152) in long/lat order.

I have never used PostgreSQL for this, but I have done this with Oracle. It appears to take the same setup for PostgreSQL as it did for Oracle:

A. Tell the database that you will be creating a geometric-based column. [Found syntax here](http://www.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2004-August/000386.html).

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('db_name', 'table_name', 'desired_column_name', 4326,
'POINT', 2);
```

Above, 4326 is a constant "SRID" denoting WGS-84.

B. Add an index to the column. [Found syntax here](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01) (this page seems *very* useful).

```
CREATE INDEX desired_index_name
ON table_name
USING gist(desired_column_name);
```

C. Add your data.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (desired_column_name)
VALUES('SRID=4326;POINT(-79.746639 43.758152)');
```

(I am curious if the above string needs to be contained by `ST_GeomFromText` based on other examples)

or ([I found here](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Transform.html))

```
INSERT INTO table_name (desired_column_name)
VALUES (ST_Transform(ST_MakePoint(-79.746639, 43.758152), 4326));
```

Note: I assume it's (X, Y), which means Longitude and Latitude ordering.

D. Query your data.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE
    ST_Contains(
        ST_Buffer(
            ST_Transform(ST_MakePoint(-79.746639, 43.758152), 4326),
            distance_probably_in_meters),
        desired_column_name);
```